# Multer, upload.single() works fine, upload.array() is not letting me select multipe images

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Hey there guys i am using Multer within A nodeJS app utilizing Express. I am trying to use multer to add simple file upload capability to a form I am rendering, so that a user can upload images with their form.

I am able to add a single image perfectly fine and can access all of its data  using

```
.post(upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
```

But I want to allow a user to upload multiple images so I am trying to change it to :

```
.post(upload.array('image'), (req, res) => {
```

As far as I can tell, all I need to do now is put 'multiple' in my form input,

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="" multiple>
```

which I am doing, but multer is not letting me select multiple files from my file picker. It is still acting as if I can only upload a single image. Instead of highlighting every image I click on, it just highlights/selects the most recently selected image. Anyone know what's going on here???

Comment: Just for context, the issue is in 'selecting' the images (ctrl+click) OR after you have selected and submitted multer is not uploading?

Just a bit confused because you say it wont let you select multiple so I'm thinking that more client side as multer has nothing to do with the image selection only the actually processing of the stream.

Comment: @proxim0 wow,  was as simple as cmd+click... I assumed I would be able to just left click on multiple files to select them.. was so puzzled i didn't even consider cmd+clicking. Works fine if I do that and lets me select multiple files. I appreciate your time and feedback.

Comment: I would suggest you to use [formidable package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

Comment: @andyroo yah, that's just the default browser behavior, there are plugins that can make that a bit nicer / more intuitive but its really all the same under the hood. Then when you select it should send it all over as part of the request. Glad you got it working!